# How do I interrupt an IPython in-process kernel embedded in a PyQt application?

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, ipython

I would like to embed an IPython widget in my application with access to objects in the same process. It seems that using the IPython in-process kernel as mentioned [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/qtconsole.html#embedding-the-qtconsole-in-a-qt-application) is the best way to do it.

However, if code executed by the embedded console blocks, the whole application blocks (e.g. if I have an infinite loop, the whole application becomes unresponsive). Is there a way to overcome this, or is this a limitation of having an inprocess-kernel ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I never found a solution and stopped looking at the problem.